# Java List/ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

So I'm making a Spigot Minecraft Plugin and its to auto mute players.
I'm making an List/ArrayList of Strings which are censored.
But it doesn't let me add to it.
Am I doing something wrong?
Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> censored = new ArrayList<String>();
censored.add("example1");
```

Thank you!

//edit

```
package me.chiz.cava.AutoMute;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Words {
    ArrayList<String> censored = new ArrayList<String>();
    censored.add("example1");
}
```

Comment: Show the uncensored code. Is it something naughty?

Comment: Show the error you get.

Comment: Nothing in your paste is wrong - you haven't supplied nearly enough detail. What error do you get, and what is your actual code?

Comment: @rzwitserloot The errors I got are <identifier> expected and illegal start of type.

Comment: @Kayaman No, it says censored as they are thats the list that I will remove from the message so like they're the censored words.

Comment: @Chiz the code you're showing shouldn't normally show that. Please [edit] your question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the error.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I edited it and added the whole file.

Comment: You can't run statements like `censored.add("example1");` within the declarations section of a class. It must be within a class constructor, a method, or a code block. If you wrapped the line curly braces you wouldn't get the error, for example the following would be OK within the declarations section of a class: `ArrayList<String> censored = new ArrayList<String>(); { censored.add("example1"); }` however is not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just dump a bunch of code in a class file. A class file defines behaviours - it isn't, itself, 'a thing you can run'. `censored.add("example1")` is a statement, it has to be in a method or constructor or initializer block.

Wrong:

```
class Example {
  ArrayList<String> censored = new ArrayList<String>();
  censored.add("example1");
}
```

correct:

```
class Example {
  ArrayList<String> censored = new ArrayList<String>();

  // This is a constructor
  Example() {
    censored.add("example1");
  }
}
```

This is *extremely* basic java. If this is throwing you for a loop sufficient to start asking questions on SO, you're trying to run before you can walk. Find a java tutorial and go through it carefully. Forget about hacking on minecraft for now, learn some java first. Then get back to it.